# Word for statement that adds no value to a conversation

Tags: single-word-requests

This shouldn't be "trite". I'm wanting a word one could say when an empty statement is made especially when it's annoying..... For example, you're driving and see a sign advertising for a massive lottery and someone says, "yah you know after taxes...." or if you're watching a news channel and a protest rally is being covered and someone (also watching) says "they just want attention".

Comment: **Like...duh!**

Comment: This is in the neighborhood of "platitude", but that doesn't *quite* connote what you're getting after, I think.

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/superfluous

Comment: "98% of all words" is the term you're looking for.

Comment: There is a term (which I can't recall right now) used in electronic communications which applies to words/data that are simply inserted to keep the "channel" occupied.  In military use this prevents an enemy from listening to an encrypted data stream and knowing whether actual data is being transmitted or not, and in other technical contexts the dummy data serves to keep transmitter and receiver synchronized and tuned to each other.

Comment: If we're talking technical terms for signal without content, the word is simply "noise".

Comment: Noise can be identified as such quite often. Uninteresting but decryptable traffic is termed padding. There was a famous case where an operator was using bits of poetry as padding, and the receiving end took the padding literally as a sacastic remark and commenced a naval engagement, so noise has its advantages, too.

Comment: Did a little Googling.  The term used for military communications (and a few other technical contexts) is "dummy traffic".  Note that this is often different from simple "noise" in that the dummy traffic will have (as much as possible) the same "color" as the real traffic.  It might, eg, be the text of *War and Peace* -- completely intelligible (once deciphered) but meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

**prattle**

> verb
>   1. talk at length in a foolish or inconsequential way. "she began to prattle on about her visit to the dentist"
>    noun
>   1. foolish or inconsequential talk. "do you intend to keep up this childish prattle?"

google prattle

Answer (score 1):

Words that add no value to a conversation are **"irrelevant"** and, sometimes, **"inappropriate"**

> - irrelevant - "unrelated to the matter being considered." [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/irrelevant)

- "Just ignore his comments. They are all irrelevant"
- "I'm going to omit the irrelevant points and just focus on his achievements."
- "What you are saying is irrelevant in this context."

Answer (score 0):

In mathematical logic statements which are always true are called **tautology**. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_%28logic%29):

> In logic, a tautology (from the Greek word ταυτολογία) is a formula that is true in every possible interpretation.

From [OED](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/tautology):

> *Logic* A statement that is true by necessity or by virtue of its logical form.

Tautologies add no scientific value to any reasoning, and thus they can be removed from proofs.

Answer (score 0):

Try [non sequitur](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/non%20sequitur)

> A statement that is not connected in a logical or clear way to anything said before it.

Answer (score -1):

It is such a beautiful word that I cannot resist putting it forward... [***pleonasm***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pleonasm).

> The use of more words than are necessary to convey meaning (e.g. *see with one’s eyes*), either as a fault of style or for emphasis.

Reference:
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pleonasm